# Why does redirecting container stdout to a file not work?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, io-redirection

I set an simple environment for testing.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY test.sh /
ENTRYPOINT /test.sh
```

---

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo "test..."
    sleep 5
done
```

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:

    test:
        image: asleea/simple_test
        entrypoint: ["/test.sh", ">", "test.log"]
        # command: [">", "/test.log"]
        container_name: simple_test
```

---

**Run the test container**

```
$docker-compose up
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Starting simple_test ... 
Starting simple_test ... done
Attaching to simple_test
simple_test | test...
simple_test | test...
```

- It is still printing `stdout` there.

---

**Check `test.log` inside the container**

```
$ docker exec -it simple_test bash
$ cd /
$ ls 
# No file named `test.log`
```

- `test.log` for redirection doesn't exist.

`docker` seems to just ignore redirection. Is it normal and why? or I did wrong way something?

### Edit

Thank you @Sebastian for your answer. it works redirecting `stdout` to a file. 
However, one more question.

The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) you refer also is saying the below.

> If you use the shell form of the CMD, then the  will execute
>   in /bin/sh -c:

As my understanding of that, `command: /test.sh > /test.log` is equivalent with `command: ["sh", "-c", "/test.sh > /test.log"]`.

However, when I did `command: /test.sh > /test.log`, it didn't redirect as well.

Why does `command: ["sh", "-c", "/test.sh > /test.log"]` work but `command: /test.sh > /test.log`.

Do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your command is executed in a shell. Try to use:

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "/test.sh", ">", "test.log" ]
```

You specified the command/ entrypoint as JSON which is called *exec form*

> The exec form does not invoke a command shell.
>   This means that normal shell processing does not happen.

[Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Comment: Thank you!. it works but could you answer one more question on my edited post?

Comment: @SangminKim It seems in docker compose you have to add `sh -c` to make it working. Have you tried your scenario with plain docker?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are doing something wrong with syntax , "command" parameter works  with compose and also did same thing as CMD. try to use **command: sh -c '/test.sh > /tmp/test.log'** in your compose file. it works fine.